# form.is_valid() not validating properly

Tags: python, django

Following is my insert.html

```
   {% csrf_token %}
       
         <div class="col-md-10">
            {{form.taxauthority|as_crispy_field}}
         </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          Select Tax Rate:
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <span id="taxrange"></span>
         
      </div>
        
     </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" name="TaxRateRange" class="form-range slider" min="0" value="16" max="100" step="0.5" id="myRange">
         </div>
         
    </div>

     </div>

     <div class="row">

     </div>

     <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col-md-12">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success col-md-8"> <i class="fas fa-database"></i>Submit</button>
        </div>
```

Here is my  views.py to handle request `

```
if request.method=="GET":
        if id==0:  #id is zero for the insert operation
           form=TaxAuthorityForm()
        else:
           obj_taxauthority=TaxAuthority.objects.get(pk=id)
           form=TaxAuthorityForm(instance=obj_taxauthority)
        return render(request,'TaxAuthority/insert.html',{'form':form})
    else:
        if id==0:
           form=TaxAuthorityForm(request.POST)
           form.taxrate=request.POST["TaxRateRange"]
           print("######### POST id=0 ##########")
           print(form.taxrate)
           print(form.errors)
           print("###################")
        else:
            obj_taxauthority=TaxAuthority.objects.get(pk=id)
            obj_taxauthority.taxrate=request.POST["TaxRateRange"]
            print("#########POST id Non Zero ##########")
            print(form.taxrate)
            print("###################")
            form=TaxAuthorityForm(request.POST,instance=obj_taxauthority)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("###################")
            print("save called")
            print("###################")
            form.save()
        return redirect('/taxauthority/')
```

I am trying to get value of slider and saving it back to the database.where  TaxAuthorityForm has two fields  taxauthority and  taxrate.    how can i set taxrate value from the range slider.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand how you are trying to use GET/POST, but if you want to use the GET method,

```
if 'id' in request.GET and request.GET['id'] != '': 
    ## Make something
    if id == 0:
        form = TaxAuthorityForm()
        context = { 'form':form }
        return render(request, 'TaxAuthority/insert.html', context)
...
```